# I can console log my state but I still get "Cannot read property 'data' of undefined". Why?

Tags: reactjs

I a trying to render a piece of text if my user status is true.

```
{this.state.userStatus.data == "true" && <div><p>aasdasdasdasdsdasd</p></div>}
```

However I get the error **Cannot read property 'data' of undefined**

The strange thing is that, if I omit the piece of code above, I can console log my userstatus and it says "true".

```
  componentDidMount() {
    this.getJobs();
    console.log
    this.getPeople();
    this.getUserStatus();
        return axios ({
            method: 'get',
            url: '/user',
            params: {},
            withCredentials: true
        }).then(result => {
          this.setState({ user: result.data }, () => {
            console.log("state in componentDidmount?", this.state.userStatus.data)
          });
        });
  }

  getUserStatus() {
    console.log("getuser status called")
    axios.get("/getUserStatus").then(result => {
      console.log("where my state at", this.state)
      this.setState({ userStatus: result.data }, () => {
          console.log("user status in getUserStatus(): ", this.state.userStatus.data)
   });
   });
}
```

Whats happening?

Comment: Did you initialize your state in the constructor ?

Comment: Are you getting `result.data` correctly? Can you please check if data exists in correct hierarchy i.e. result.data .

And yes please check, 
`this.setState({ user: result.data }, () => {
            console.log("state in componentDidmount?", this.state.userStatus.data)
          });`
For this, check 1st answer!

Answer (score 1):

extend your condition to

```
{this.state.userStatus && this.state.userStatus.data == "true" && <div><p>aasdasdasdasdsdasd</p></div>}
```

Answer (score 0):

`state.userStatus` is undefined until the call returns.

Answer (score 0):

Try to initialize your state

```
constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            this.state = {userStatus: {}};
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

at the first try to check the value of state by using console.log(this.state.userStatus) and show what the value and show it is updated and it found or not and check if this .state.userStatus if found the check the this .state.userStatus.data ==" true" that right   if it noot found  the condition false it will not show the text because you used  and  operation  the first condition not true then not show the text